# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error in tutorial

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm in the process of learning about Java EE, Glassfish and EJBs by following [this excellent tutorial](http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/).

I'm stuck at section 9.i . I got the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException error the author mentioned and did the same fixes he did. However, I still get the same error and I've been looking for an answer for quite some time now. Here's what I tried.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="cookbookEJB">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/cookbook</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.davidlacerte.cookbook.entity.City</class>
        <class>com.davidlacerte.cookbook.entity.Country</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Glassfish install does have a jdbc/cookbook JDBC resource. Now, I added the following code because the Glassfish stack trace was less than helpful:

```
@Override
public long countryCount() {
    try
    {
    return eao.countCountries();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Throwable t = e.getCause();

        while(t != null)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
            t = t.getCause();
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
INFO: Exception thrown from bean: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 16 in method com.davidlacerte.cookbook.entity.City._persistence_checkFetched(Ljava/lang/String;)V at offset 5
INFO: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 16 in method com.davidlacerte.cookbook.entity.City._persistence_checkFetched(Ljava/lang/String;)V at offset 5
```

I googled the "Excepting a stackmap frame..." error, many blogs suggested adding a `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` parameter to my VM arguments : I did, no luck.

So, that's all I know and all I've tried for now. As I said I don't know much about EJB and Glassfish so if you need more info, just ask. I'm going slightly mad, here.

**EDIT** : just re-read the server log and found this :

```
WARNING: Container org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSContainer@3dbfc326 doesn't support class com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.Module
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The VerifyError seems to be a bug that has been fixed more than one year ago with EclipseLink 2.3. If you are using an older version, you'd better upgrade to that version or to the latest stable (2.4)

Comment: @perissf : I upgraded EclipseLink to the latest version and my EJB project is correctly configured for EclipeLink 2.4.x and I'm still getting this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I hate this but I downgraded to the 1.6 JDK and it's working perfectly. For lack of a better solution (I prefer running the latest and greatest), use the 1.6 version.

Comment: In this case, you were hitting the exact bug described here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339388 . If upgrading to 2.4 didn't solve the problem, it probably means that your project is using the EclipseLink version deployed in GlassFish, not in your application's classpath.